# Primefaces <p:selectOneMenu Converter with Omnifaces

Tags: primefaces, converters, omnifaces

I have a problem with the selectedArticleGroup is allways **NULL** !!!

Here my classes:

```
                <p:selectOneMenu id="categorie_article"
                    value="#{articleGroupListController.selectedArticleGroup}"
                    effect="fade" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter"
                    filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" noSelectionOption="true" />
                    <f:selectItems
                        value="#{articleGroupListController.articleListGroup}"
                        var="articleListGroup" itemLabel="#{articleListGroup.name}" itemValue="#{articleListGroup}"  />
                    <f:ajax render="selected_item" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
```

The bean:

```
    @SessionScoped
    @Named
    public class ArticleGroupListController implements Serializable {
    ....
        private ArticleGroup selectedArticleGroup;
......GETTER + SETTER
```

The implementation of the converter is in the omnifaces jar.

The problem is: the articleGroupListController.selectedArticleGroup is allways null.
Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: Do you have overridden `toString()` method of `ArticleGroup` class? How did you observe that it's null; by debugging in the setter method, or by debugging in the action method? If the action method, have you checked the setter method instead?